# Stay logged in on a website in an application lifecycle

Tags: android

I was able log in through my android app to http://yearbook08.com/ using this code:

```
    String URL="http://yearbook08.com/login.php";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpResponse response = null;


    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL); 
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userId", uname));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }



    try {
        response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Now when I move to another activity I want to retrieve http://yearbook08.com/wall.php but the web server does not recognize my last login and asks me to login again.

Is there a way that I can stay logged in after once logging in? Kindly help !

Comment: Why don't you make a Webservice with username/password credentials? It would be easy if you do this.

Comment: Paresh ! I am new to this I will appreciate if you elaborate please

Comment: Generally the way you mentioned above is not the Standard and proposed practice. Instead create a webservice using PHP/.NET/JAVA, by which you can exchange information between web database and clients like android, iPhone, BB, WP7 or any device.

Comment: No need to use webservice, check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not take into account session management. This happening as after a successful login no cookies are set, so if you send another request the initial authentication is lost and server takes it to be a fresh request.
I would suggest you use Apache httpcomponents library 4.x (httpclient in particular)

Create a httpcontext and attach a cookie store as

```
// Create a local instance of cookie store
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
// Create local HTTP context
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
// Bind custom cookie store to the local context
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"); 
// Pass local context as a parameter
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
```

Make use the same localContext in the subsequent requests. Also note cookiestore and httpcontext should be declared as static or global variables as their scope must exist wherever you carry the httprequest. You don't have to set cookies on your own, it is automatically done!
And do read about HttpComponents 4.x http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html

**Update 1:**
Make sure it is v4 and v3. basicCookiestore has only been present since v4. It is clear now that you are using v3 which does not know about basiccookiestore object. Add the v4 library to your project. It will solve your problem

**Update 2**
If you try to retrieve http://yearbook08.com/wall.php from the 2nd activity this problem will arise as the 2nd activity won't have httpcontext,httpclient or the Cookiestore object in it. So it will send a fresh request.
**1st approach**
 So you should try to fetch the contents you need in the first activity itself and then pass on the fetched data to the 2nd activity. This way you'll have session maintained.
**2nd soln**
 If you are not satisfied with this you can check this out http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-implementing-global-state-share-data-between-activities-and-across-your-application/ Share httpcontext, cookiestore and httpclient across the activities to accomplish the task.

Comment: Thanks Shikhar but I have already tried this, the problem with this is when I write
      CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
  It asks me to cast it like
       CookieStore cookieStore =(CookieStore)new BasicCookieStore();

and by casting it like this makes the code  crash at this very line :(

Comment: Read my answer. Check this link http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicCookieStore.html ,it mentions since v4....

Comment: I ain't getting ne where how can i update http components version :/ can u help please ?

Comment: Download this file http://apache.techartifact.com/mirror//httpcomponents/httpclient/binary/httpcomponents-client-4.2.1-bin.zip Extract it and put httpclient-4.2.jar in your project. Right click and add it to your build path. In all the java classes where you have used httpclient, httppost etc remove the imports (as they refer to Android's default v3) then press ctrl+shift+o (alphabet not 0) It will include the proper imports. If all the steps are properly done, you shouldn't get any error with CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore(); line.

Comment: Every thing done and it does not show any error at the line 
 CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
The night mare persist as the server still does not recognize me , i have also used the objects  cookie store  and local context as global variables

Comment: Shikhar unfortunately yesterday I did make them global in the very way you suggested but it did not work out either. By making them global I also checked and I get the updated values in 2nd activity :( I dont know whats worng :/